# HTML/CSS position absolute for parent and children

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, absolute

Convert the boxes into cocentric circles (circles within each other that share the same center). The outer circle should be black with a size of 300px and the inner circle should be white with a size of 200px.

html:

```
<div id="p10">
    <div id="outer">
        <div class="rectangle" id="inner"></div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#p10 #outer {
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
}

#p10 #inner {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

The css works only if `#p10 #outer` position's absolute. I'm kind of confused on why this is so. Does this mean that any time I want a subelement position's to be absolute, all of the parent's positions must be absolute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of a `position:absolute` element is relative to the closest container with which the position is set to either `absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`, otherwise it is relative to the viewport.

It can also be relative to the initial containing block if none of the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` offset value was specified.

There could be more possibilities, you can learn more on [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position), and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Answer (score 0):

just change the position relative of parent div

```
 #p10 #outer {
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-color: #000;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use position:absolute for the outer and position:relative for the inner. Then, set the border-radius property at half the width in pixels. Percentage in border-radius could cause some problems. Naturally you need to center the inner, so give it these properties.

```
#inner {
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width:200px;
border-radius:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute/relative might not be neede here , at least relative for inner content.

you can also relay on padding and mind [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

```css
#p10 #outer {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding:50px;
  border-color: #000;
  /*position: absolute;*//* did you need it ? it will work the same for the child; */
  box-sizing:content-box; /*make sure padding is not included in size calculation*/
}
#p10 #inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="p10">
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="rectangle" id="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

you can also relay on marging and mind [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing):

```css
#p10 #outer {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-color: #000;
  /*position: absolute;*//* did you need it ? it will work the same for the child; */
  padding:1px; /* mind [collapsing margins][1] */
}
#p10 #inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="p10">
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="rectangle" id="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

You may also use flex :

```css
#p10 #outer {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  border-color: #000;
  /*position: absolute;*//* did you need it ? it will work the same for the child; */
}
#p10 #inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="p10">
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="rectangle" id="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

You can also use a single box

```css
.circle {
  /* diplay, float, position, .. whatever is needed to be inserted mong the rest of your document styles*/
  margin:55px;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border:solid;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50px gray, 0 0 0 53px;
  border-radius:50%;
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```